# When a CM abelian variety has complex multiplication by $\mathcal{O}_E$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, abelian-varieties, complex-multiplication

I'm reading Milne's note, Complex Multiplication. There are many properties, such as Shimura-Taniyama Formula provided that $A$ is an abelian variety with complex multiplication by $\mathcal{O}_E$. So I want to know that if there are properties about when a CM abelian variety has complex multiplication by $\mathcal{O}_E$?

Edit: $\mathcal{O}_E$ is the rings of integers in $E$. The condition means that the abelian variety has complex multiplication by $E$ and End$(A)\cap E=\mathcal{O}_E$.

Thank you!

Comment: What is $\mathscr{O}_E$?